# Vue doesn't update when global instance property changes

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code in my `app.js` (after importing Vue and before `new Vue()`):

```js
Vue.prototype.$globalArray = [];
```

And in one of my Vue components I have the following:

```html
<span v-for="item in $globalArray">{{ item }}</span>
```

The problem then is that when I do `$vm0.$globalArray.push('some text');` in my Chrome dev tools (with the Vue extension hence the `$vm0`), nothing happens.
However when I change my `app.js` to

```js
Vue.prototype.$globalArray = 'some other text';
```

It does actually show the 'some other text' so it looks like it only renders the initial value but doesn't update. The same goes for when I set a timeout of a couple of seconds after the component has mounted and then insert something in the `$globalArray`.

Could someone tell me whether I'm doing something wrong or that this is not supported?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining just a global vue instance and it isn't reactive by default - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html

To make it reactive you can follow Vue.observable for example - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable

```js
Vue.prototype.$global = Vue.observable({array: []})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not work for me directly. What **did** work for me however, is `Vue.observable({array: []})` and then render and push to `$globalArray.array`. Is that what you actually meant? Or should your exact answer also work and am I doing something wrong?